# Unable to read excel file from Python 3.6

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am unable to read excel files. I am having MS Excel 2016.

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r'dummy.xlsx','r') as exl:
  p = pd.ExcelFile(exl)
  print(p.sheet_names)


runfile('C:/Users/ESETPRI/Documents/My Python Scripts/pdf read.py', wdir='C:/Users/ESETPRI/Documents/My Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-eb59316a92ec>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/ESETPRI/Documents/My Python Scripts/pdf read.py', wdir='C:/Users/ESETPRI/Documents/My Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Users\ESETPRI\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\ESETPRI\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/ESETPRI/Documents/My Python Scripts/pdf read.py", line 11, in <module>
p = pd.ExcelFile(exl)

  File "C:\Users\ESETPRI\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 291, in __init__
data = io.read()

  File "C:\Users\ESETPRI\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 634: character maps to <undefined>
```

Tried different type of encoding UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII, CP1252 but no success. Even the tried with an empty xlsx file, same result.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 14: invalid start byte

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 602-603: illegal encoding

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 634: character maps to <undefined>

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**EDIT**

Tried 'latin-1' as well

```
 File "C:\Users\ESETPRI\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 672, in get2bytes
return (BYTES_ORD(hi) << 8) | BYTES_ORD(lo)

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus definitely not a dupe of that: 1. The error isn't even the same, 2. The dupe addresses a Python 2 problem while OP is using Python 3.

Comment: Have you tried reading with `pd.read_excel()` .?

Comment: directly try with `pd.ExcelFile('dummy.xlsx')` instead of `with open()`.

Comment: @VikasDamodar tried `pd.ExcelFile('dummy.xlsx')` its working fine but 'open(..)' is throwing error..any explanation

Comment: open you mean `with open()` ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar both `with open(r'dummy.xlsx','r')` and `exl=open(r'dummy.xlsx','r')`

Comment: If you are using `pd.ExcelFile()` it is expecting a file name as string, but when you open it with a file object and if you are giving that file object to pd.ExcelFile() it wont accept it, because it requires a filename in string format to open and process. If you already open it with a variable it will be a file object, file object cant be process to pd.ExcelFile.

Comment: Thanks for explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) try `read_excel`

```
>>> pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx')
      Name  Value
0  string1      1
1  string2      2
2  string3      3
```

Comment: `pd.ExcelFile('dummy.xlsx')` and `pd.read_excel('dummy.xlsx')` are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

With pandas

```
workbook_df=pd.ExcelFile(input_file_path)
key_sheet = workbook_df.parse("KEY")
```

With openpyxl

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file_path)
write_output = wb.get_sheet_by_name('OUTPUT')
```